# How can I request a server in url take with username and password

Tags: internet-explorer, url

http://pub:123@myipaddress/axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi?resolution=4CIF

when I use the url address , it shows different in the chrome,firefox and IE 9

1) chrome can give me a picture and display.

2) firefox first show me a check dialog box, when you click ok, it can give me the right picture.

3) IE 9, it shows me 'Windows cannot find....' dialog box

Is there any way to access the camera server like the chrome browser.

I want to use asp.net to request the camera server, when using `http://myipaddress/axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi?resolution=4CIF` , it shows the `Windows Security` dialog box for the username and password.

I hope to send the username and password in the c# code and I don't want to see the 'Windows Security' dialog box , But I don't want to set up `Enable anonymous viewer login` in the camera server's users setup .

Is there any way to solve it ?

Comment: In C#.net , using url = "http://192.168.101.110/axis-cgi/com/ptz.cgi?query=position" in method  private string GetResult(string url)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string result = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(client.DownloadData(url));

        return result;
    } , when run to the client.DownloadData(url) , it respose 'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    byte[] result = client.DownloadData(url);
```

In C#.net , We can use WebClient's Credetials Property to send the username and password

Answer (score 0):

you need to take the username and password and embed them into the object

```
<html>
<head>
<title>H.264 Live View</title>
</head>
<body>

<div align="center"><h2>H.264 Live View</h2>
<form name="test">
  <input id="ip" type="input" size="10" value="0.0.0.0">
  <input type="button" name="Play" value="Play" onClick="OnPlay(); return false;">
</form>
<object id="Player" height="480" width="640" border="1"
  classid="CLSID:745395C8-D0E1-4227-8586-624CA9A10A8D">
  <param name="AutoStart" value="1">
  <param name="UIMode" value="none">
  <param name="MediaType" value="h264">
  <param name="NetworkTimeout" value="5000"><!-- use this param if you want to change the network timeout -->
  <param name="MediaUsername" value=""><!-- this param only necessary if restricted access is enabled -->
  <param name="MediaPassword" value=""><!-- this param only necessary if restricted access is enabled -->
  <param name="MediaURL" value="axrtpu://myServer/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264"><!-- your media url goes here -->
</object>
</div>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--      
    document.Player.EnableContextMenu = true;
    document.Player.StretchToFit = true;
    document.Player.MaintainAspectRatio = true;
//-->
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function OnPlay()
{
  try
  {
    var server = document.getElementById('ip').value;
    // return values from AMC methods are handled as exceptions in JavaScript
    document.Player.Stop();
    document.Player.MediaURL = "axrtsphttp://" + server + "/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264";
    document.Player.Play();
  }
  catch(e){}
}
//-->
</script>

<script language="JavaScript" for="Player" event="OnError(theError, theMsg)">
<!--
  alert(theError + ' ' + theMsg);
//-->
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks , but if I don't want to use the embed object, can I access. Is  there some Axis Communications company's API can do this job ? I can't find in Axis Communications company's VAPIX®  doc.